# Illegal State Exception when Painting TextView as StrikeThrough

Tags: android

I am creating a To Do List application. When a task is marked as "Completed" the TextView will be painted as strikethrough text.

The issue is when I have more than one task in my list and the last task in the list (the bottom of the list) was marked as "Completed" then deleted, if I were to add another task, the TextView is still painted as StrikeThrough text. So I then modified my code to be:

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity implements OnMenuItemClickListener {

private EditText taskInput;
private ListView listItem;
private ArrayAdapter<Task> aAdapter;
private ArrayList<Task> tasksList;
private String taskName;
private int taskLoc;
public TextView strikeThrough;
private OfflineTaskDAO otDAO;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_list);

    taskInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTask);
    listItem = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.taskList);  

    //attach the onItemClickListener to the ListView
    listItem.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        //method to run when an item is clicked         
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

             //get the position of the selected item
             taskLoc = position;

             //get the task at that position
             Task clickedTask = tasksList.get(taskLoc);

             //show the popup menu 
             showMenu(v, clickedTask);
        }
    });

    //initialize the array of tasks
    tasksList = new ArrayList<Task>();

    otDAO = new OfflineTaskDAO(this);

    tasksList = otDAO.getAllTasks();

    //initialize the array adapter that will use a textview as a list row item
    aAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Task>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tasksList);

    //set the adapter for the ListView
    listItem.setAdapter(aAdapter);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Strikethrough the text if any of the tasks are completed
    for (Task task : tasksList){
        strikethroughText(task);
    }

    aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    //Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menu){
    switch (menu.getItemId()){
    case R.id.action_delete:
        onDeleteAllClicked(null);
        return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menu);
    }
}

/**
 * Method to run when an item in the list view is selected
 * 
 * @param v
 * @param task - the task that was selected
 */
public void showMenu(View v, Task task){

    //if the task is not completed, show a pop up that has the option "Complete"
    if(task.getCompleted() == false){           
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        popup.inflate(R.menu.complete_popup);
        popup.show();
    } 

    //if the task is completed, show a pop up that has the option "Uncomplete"
    if(task.getCompleted() == true){

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        popup.inflate(R.menu.uncomplete_popup);
        popup.show();
    }


}   

/**
 * Method to run when a menu item is clicke
 */
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){

    //if Complete or Uncomplete menu items were selected, complete the task
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.Complete || item.getItemId() == R.id.Uncomplete){
        completeTask(taskLoc);
    } 

    //if delete menu item was selected, delete the task
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.Delete) {
        onDeleteClicked();
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Method to run when the add button is clicked
 */
public void onAddClicked(View v){
    createTask();
}

/**
 * Method to run when the Delete All Tasks  menu button is clicked. Will display a popup to ask the user
 * if they really want to delete all tasks. 
 * @param v
 */
public void onDeleteAllClicked(View v){
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch(which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                clearCompletedTasks();
                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                dialog.dismiss();
                break;
            }

        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete all completed tasks?").setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener).show();
}

/**
 * Method to run when the Delete Task menu item is clicked. Will display a popup to ask the user
 * if they really want to delete the task. 
 * @param v
 */
public void onDeleteClicked(){
    Task task = tasksList.get(taskLoc);

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch(which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                deleteTask(taskLoc);
                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                dialog.dismiss();
                break;
            }

        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete "+ task.toString()+ "?").setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener).show();
}

/**
 * Method to take user input and display it in a listview
 */
private void createTask() {

    //if the user input is longer than 0 characters
    if (taskInput.getText().length() > 0){

        //create a task
        Task t = new Task();

        //set the description to the user input
        t.setDescription(taskInput.getText().toString());

        //add task description to the ArrayList of tasks
        tasksList.add(t);

        //add the ArrayList to the database
        otDAO.insertTask(tasksList);

        //reset the input box so more can be input
        taskInput.setText("");

        //update the ListView to show the newly added task
        aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    } 
    else {          
        //if user input is not longer than 0 characters, show a toast
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter a task", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        t.show();
    }
    //run the strikethroughText method to fix any issues
    for (Task task : tasksList){
        strikethroughText(task);
    }
}

/**
 * Method to delete a task once the option is selected in the popup menu
 * 
 * @param itemId - location of the selected item
 */
private void deleteTask(int itemId){
    if (itemId >= 0){

        //get the task that was selected
        Task deleteTask = tasksList.get(itemId);

        //get the task name of the selected item
        taskName = deleteTask.getDescription();

        otDAO.deleteDatabaseRecord(deleteTask);

        //remove the item from the ArrayList
        tasksList.remove(itemId);

        //show toast explaining what happened
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, taskName + " has been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        t.show();
    }

    //Strikethrough the text if any of the tasks are completed
    for (Task task : tasksList){
        strikethroughText(task);
    }

        //tell the array adapter that something changed
        aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * Method to complete a task once the option is seleceted in the popup menu.
 * It also will strikethrough the text to show that it has been completed.
 * 
 * @param itemId - location of the selected item
 */
private void completeTask(int itemId){
    if(itemId >= 0){            
        //TextView taskDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.taskList);

        //get the task that was selected
        Task completeTask = tasksList.get(itemId);

        //get the name of the task that was selected
        taskName = completeTask.getDescription();

        //if the task has not been completed, set mark as completed, strikethrough the text, show a toast 
        if(completeTask.getCompleted() == false){

            //set completed to true
            completeTask.setCompleted(true);

            //strikethrough the text
            strikethroughText(completeTask);

            //update the database
            otDAO.updateDatabaseRecord(completeTask);

            //show toast explaining what has happened
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, taskName + " has been completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            t.show();
        }

        //if the task has been completed, mark as not completed, un-strikethrough the text, show a toast
        else{

            //set the task completed to false
            completeTask.setCompleted(false);

            //un-strikethrough the text
            strikethroughText(completeTask);

            //update the database
            otDAO.updateDatabaseRecord(completeTask);

            //show toast explaining what has happened
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, taskName + " has not been completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            t.show();

        }

        //tell the array adapter that something changed
        aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public void strikethroughText(Task task){

    //if the task is completed,
    if(task.getCompleted() == true){

        //get the location of the task in the ArrayList
        int locID = tasksList.indexOf(task);

        //and strikethrough the text
        strikeThrough = (TextView) listItem.getChildAt(locID);
        strikeThrough.setPaintFlags(strikeThrough.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);           
    }

    //if the task isn't completed,
    if(task.getCompleted() == false){

        //get the location of the task in the ArrayList
        int locID = tasksList.indexOf(task);

        //and un-strikethrough the text
        strikeThrough = (TextView) listItem.getChildAt(locID);
        strikeThrough.setPaintFlags(strikeThrough.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));            
    } 
}

/**
 * Method to clear all completed tasks. This method is invoked on the press
 * of a button.
 */
private void clearCompletedTasks(){

    Iterator<Task> it = tasksList.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Task task = it.next();
        if(task.getCompleted() == true){
            it.remove();
            otDAO.deleteDatabaseRecord(task);
        }
    }

    Toast t = Toast.makeText(this,"All completed tasks have been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    t.show();

    //run the strikethroughText method to fix any issues
    for (Task task : tasksList){
        strikethroughText(task);
    }
    aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

The added part is in the createTaks() method. I put in the lines:

```
for (Task task : tasksList){
        strikethroughText(task);
    }
```

When that method is run on the newly added task I get the error:

```
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not                       execute method of the activity
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    at     android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3838)
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3833)
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    ... 11 more
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    at com.todo.ui.ListActivity.strikethroughText(ListActivity.java:366)
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    at com.todo.ui.ListActivity.createTask(ListActivity.java:249)
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    at             com.todo.ui.ListActivity.onAddClicked(ListActivity.java:155)
11-30 18:08:59.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24292):    ... 14 more
```

If it helps, I can include a link to the application.

Any and all help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is line 366:

```
strikeThrough.setPaintFlags(strikeThrough.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
```

Comment: What's on line 366 of ListActivity?

Comment: Can you edit your code to highlight which line of your strikethroughText() is 366. Then we might be able to work out what's causing the null pointer exception on that line.

Comment: I edited the original post to show line 366. That line is part of the method strikethroughText(Task task).

Comment: Looks like the TextView strikeThrough is null. Check the value of locID at that point, and verify that the ListVie contains that child.